# How to remove this shower control handle?

Tags: bathroom, shower, faucet

I have this Gerber shower handle that controls the shower and there is a small leak that I am trying to fix but I can't find any screws or button on this to remove and check the seal/cartilage

[image: Gerber shower single handle without screw/button]

Comment: did you try unscrewing the hand grip

Comment: Or the screw(s) in the escutcheon plate?